# How to tell Chrome not use local cache prematurely

Tags: http, caching, nginx, http-caching

The page (just a static `.html`) is served with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:59:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:53:23 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Then, I close the tab, open the page again (by typing the url manually) and get the next response:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:58:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:53:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55b84023-1ad"
```

I repeat it several times and then Chrome stops requesting it from the server and serves directly from its cache.

```
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:59:56 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 29 Jul 2015 02:53:23 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Is there a way (server side) to tell Chrome not to do that, but respect HTTP caching headers on every request?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: @aa333 not sure it's relevant